# jaxb create xml attribute

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, jaxb

I want to create xml from my object, but instead of xml nodes I'd like to create attribute i.e.

```
@XmlRootElement
class MyObject{
 private String name;
 private String age;
 ...getters/setters...
}
```

And I want my object to create this xml :

```
<MyObject name="something">
   <age></age>
</MyObject>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `@XmlAttribute` annotation to map to an XML attribute.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class MyObject{

 @XmlAttribute // Maps to an XML attribute
 private String name;


 private String age; // Maps to an XML element
 ...getters/setters...
}
```